# Get user and users of ancestors of a model instance if it has `organizationmember` attribute or else only user of the instance in Django

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
class Client(BaseModel):
    #other fields
    engineers = models.ManyToManyField(Engineer, null = True, blank = True, related_name='clients')

class OrganizationMember(MPTTModel):
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Now I would like to get `all engineers` of a `client` instance and check if each `engineer` has an `organizationmember` instance or not.
Then if they belong to some organization then I should `get_ancestors` of that `organizationmember` and then the users.
If they do not have any `organizationmember` then just get the user of that engineer instance.

For this I have written a method in `Client` model as below:

```
class Client(BaseModel):

    def get_users_from_engineers(self):
        users_in_organization = []
        users_outside_organization = []

        engineers = self.engineers.all()
        if engineers:
            for engineer in engineers:
                user = engineer.user
                if hasattr(user, "organizationmember"):
                    users_in_organization += [orgmember.user for orgmember in user.organizationmember.get_ancestors(include_self=True)]
                else:
                    users_outside_organization.append(user)
```

Now this code is working correctly but I am sure that I can use django filters here instead of two `for` loops and optimize this code. But I do not know how.

For eg:

```
OrganizationMember.objects.filter(user__engineer__in=self.engineers.all())
```

can be used to get all the `organizationmembers` of the `engineers` of that particular `client` instance. But I need the users of those `organizationmembers`.
Also if I use `get_ancestors` on multiple engineers then more than one engineer might have the same ancestor thereby adding the same person more than once in the `users_in_organization` list. How can I rectify this if I use django filters?

Edit:

In the method `get_users_from_engineers` I can also use as follows:

```
users_outside_organization = list(User.objects.filter(engineer__in=engineers, organizationmember__isnull=True)
```

But I do not know how to get the `users_in_organization` values as stated above using django orm methods.

Note: This is my first question in **codereview**. I do not know if this question should be asked here or in **stackoverflow** since I already have a working code. Anyway I have asked the same question in **stackoverflow** also. Please feel free to correct me regarding the same.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have changed the title of the question now.

Comment: Your title is still about your code, and not what it does. There are mentions of organizations and members in your code: that is what your code's function is, not general things like "getting data". Look at the link I posted, look at other questions here. Please follow the guidelines.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I have made further changes to the title as per the guidelines and your suggestions in the comments.